# Sharepoint Redirecting Users or Groups from a page to another

Tags: sharepoint, redirect, usergroups

What I am tring to do is, when people comes to that page:

http://server:26521/MY_Portal/service/default.aspx

I want them to be redirected to that page

http://server:26521/default.aspx

Depending on their User name Or User Group.

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to do this:

- If you're using ISA Server or a similiar product in front of Sharepoint, you can configure it to do this. So those users who you want redirected will never access the first page.
- Alternatively, you could write a webpart, which analyzes who the user is, and does some sort of redirection, either in .net or in javascript to the page you want.